# Mouse hover acction

Tags: selenium

I am facing one issue, while performing mouse hover action.
While script is running mouse hover action, if we suddenly move the system mouse manually then script getting failed 
how to handle this, while performing mouse over action, if we move the system mouse my script should not fail

Comment: please include your code so we can take a look

Comment: Okya thq for your replay :-)